# How do you make an app launch when Mac is awake?

Tags: macos, applescript

How do you use Apple Script to make an app launch when the Mac is awoken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla AppleScript can't do that.

There are third-party (Cocoa) tools like [PowerManager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) or [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de) which observe the appropriate notifications of `NSWorkspace` and execute scripts or perform other tasks.